# Ref in async Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, windows-store-apps

How I can to pass a reference as a parameter to Async method in Windows Store App ? 
 I'm looking for something like this:

```
var a = DoThis(ref obj.value);

public async Task DoThis(ref int value)
{
    value = 10;
}
```

But error:

> Async methods cannot have ref or out parameters

Has any another way?

Note:
I need to pass exactly obj.value. This method would be used by different types of objects, by same type of objects, by one object, but I will pass obj.val_1, obj.val_2 or obj.val_10. All values will be same type (for ex string)

Answer (score 17):

If you don't care about a little overhead and possibly prolonged lifetime of your objects, you could emulate the ref behavior by passing a setter and a getter method to the function, like this:

```
public async Task DoStuff(Func<int> getter, Action<int> setter)
{
    var value1 = getter();
    await DoSomeOtherAsyncStuff();
    setter(value1 * value1);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
await DoStuff(() => obj.Value, x => obj.Value = x);
```

Comment: I believe this is a great answer for quite a few reasons, and he can extend the reusability for his many different kinds of object by making it generic: `DoStuff<T>(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter)`.

Comment: Nate Diamond I think Func and Action are already Generic type Delegates

Answer (score 11):

You could directly pass the object itself and set the value of the corresponding property inside the method:

```
var a = DoThis(obj);

public async Task DoThis(SomeObject o)
{
    o.value = 10;
}
```

And if you do not have such object simply write one and have the async method take that object as parameter:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please, read the question: I need to pass exactly obj.value. This method would be used by different types of objects, by same type of objects, by one object, but I will pass obj.val_1, obj.val_2 or obj.val_10

Comment: Please read the error message you are getting: THIS IS NOT SUPPORTED in C# and unless you write a compiler yourself that supports passing ref/out variables to `async` methods I don't see how you could solve your problem. What else do you expect me to tell you? Show you a working example of how to do something that is not supported?

Comment: My question is: "Has any another way?" Answer must be short: "No, because...." or "Yes, you need to do...." And answer which you already provide unhelpful.

Comment: Be nice. This answer was exceptionally helpful; I needed to do pass ref-equivalent parameters to an async method, and the other answer w/ the getter and setter could not be made properly threadsafe, but this one can.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use the `Task<>` class and return the desired value. Then Your code would look something like:

```
var a = DoThis(obj.value);
obj.value = a.Result;

public async Task<int> DoThis(int value)
{
    int result = value + 10; //compute the resulting value
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, the other way to go with this that I can think of is encapsulating the update of the given object's member in a method and then passing an action invoking this method as the task's argument, like so:

```
var a = DoThis(() => ChangeValue(ref obj.value));

public void ChangeValue(ref int val)
{
    val = 10;
}

public async Task DoThis(Action act)
{
    var t = new Task(act);
    t.Start();
    await t;
}
```

As far as I tested it the change was made in the child thread, but still it's effect was visible in the parent thread. Hope this helps You.

Comment: i know about that way, but I'm looking for way, that I can change value inside async Task. But +1 for you.

Comment: about your edit: you are not allowed to use ref parameter inside lambda expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this as you have it (as you know). So, a few work arounds:

You can do this by passing the initial object since it will be a reference type

```
var a = DoThis(obj);  

public async Task DoThis(object obj) //replace the object with the actual object type
{
    obj.value = 10;
}
```

**EDIT**

Based upon your comments, create an interface and have your classes implement it (providing it's always the same type you want to pass). Then you can pass the interface which is shared (maybe over kill, depends on your needs, or even unrealistic amount of work).

Or, provide a base class with the property! (I don't like this suggestion but since you're asking for something which can't be done it may suffice although I don't recommend it).

An example of the interface is here (not using what you have, but close enough using a Colsone App)

```
using System;

namespace InterfacesReferenceTypes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass mc = new MyClass();
            DoThis(mc);
            Console.WriteLine(mc.Number);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void DoThis(IDemo id)
        {
            id.Number = 10;
        }
     }

    class MyClass : IDemo
    {
        //other props and methods etc
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    interface IDemo
    {
        int Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

After next comments, you will have to still use an interface, but re assign the value afterwards. I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but this works:

```
using System.Text;

namespace InterfacesRerefenceTypes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass mc = new MyClass();
            Console.WriteLine(mc.Number);
            mc.val1 = 3;
            mc.val2 = 5;
            mc.Number = mc.val2;
            DoThis(mc);
            mc.val2 = mc.Number;

            Console.WriteLine(mc.val2);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void DoThis(IDemo id)
        {
            id.Number = 15;
        }
    }

    class MyClass : IDemo
    {
        public int val1 { get; set; }
        public int val2 { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    interface IDemo
    {
        int Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, read the question: I need to pass exactly obj.value. This method would be used by different types of objects, by same type of objects, by one object, but I will pass obj.val_1, obj.val_2 or obj.val_10

Comment: @jimpanzer, I did - your post never mentions it will be used by different types of objects! Can I assume though that val_1, val_2 etc will all be the same type?

Comment: val_1, val_2, val_10 - all the same type (string or int or another, but the SAME). I need to pass only value, because I get this value from different places.

Comment: @jimpanzer, Updated - you may be able to use an Interface for this

Comment: I understand your idea, but in MyClass can be Number, Number1, Nuber2... and many other numbers. And I want pass only Value. But thanks, that you spend your time.

Comment: @jimpanzer, OK, this is my last attempt :) Again, not the nicest solution but it gives you an idea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30307/discussion-between-jimpanzer-and-dave-rook)

Comment: @jimpanzer, I'm sorry, I just don't have any more time today. Good luck though, hopefully it helps at least!