# How can I convert a function with a ref paramter to an async function?

Tags: c#, iis, android-asynctask, async-await

I have the following function which I want to convert to an async / non locking function.

Here is the function in its currenc form:

```
   private static void BlockForResponse(ref bool localFlag)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (!localFlag)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            if (count++ > 50)   // 200 * 50 = 10 seconds
            {
                //timeout
                throw new TimeOutException();
            }
        }
    }
```

here is my attempt:

```
  private static async Task BlockForResponse(ref bool localFlag)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (!localFlag)
        {
            await Task.Delay(200);
            if (count++ > 50)   // 200 * 50 = 10 seconds
            {
                //timeout
                throw new TimeOutException();
            }
        }
    }
```

however I get a compile error saying that async functions cant have ref or out parameters. However this is the core functionality of the function.

Is it possible to convert it to an async function?

Explanation of code:

I must admit this is an odd piece of code, let me try an explain what its trying to do:

so there is a 3rd party dll which I need to use. Which provides me with services, I sadly have no control over this dll.

The way it works, 
I call a command in the dll providing it a callback function which it calls once it has finished the task.

I can only move on to what I want to do once I have the result from that call.  hence the need fro this function.

I make the call to the dll, providing it with a call back function:

```
    private bool _commandFlag = false;
    private bool _commandResponse;

    public async Task ExecuteCommand(string userId, string deviceId)
    {
        var link = await LinkProviderAsync.GetDeviceLinkAsync(deviceId, userId);
        try
        {               
            //execute command
            if (link.Command(Commands.ConnectToDevice, CallBackFunction))
            {
                BlockForResponse(ref _commandFlag);
                return;     //Received a response
            }
            else
            {   //Timeout Error                    
                throw new ConnectionErrorException();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private void CallBackFunction(bool result)
    {
        _commandResponse = result;
        _commandFlag = true;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ref in async Task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664823/ref-in-async-task)

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? This looks like a fairly odd method to start with... perhaps you just want to use a `CancellationToken` instead, or a `Task` so that you know when the task has completed?

Comment: I agree with Jon (hi Jon! :) ). There's more fishy going on here than just not being able to pass by-ref. At the very least, there's the lack of volatile read on the flag, potentially causing a thread-safety issue. And as Jon notes, the semantics of the code appears consistent with some cancelation scenario, suggesting that it would be better to use pre-existing .NET mechanisms to support (e.g. CancellationToken, or maybe Monitor for cross-thread signaling, depending on the exact scenario).

Comment: Please see my updated info in the question. that will hopefully provide a better understanding of the code / question at hand.

Comment: so you want if out side the code if you set the **localFlag = true;** this code should stopped immediately.. right? then its not the right approach.. use the timer which check the localFlag every tick..

Comment: Yes that is what I want to achieve. And still some how not block, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The way it works, I call a command in the dll providing it a callback function which it calls once it has finished the task.

Then what you really want is to use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to create a TAP method, something [similar to this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#EAP).

```
public static Task<bool> CommandAsync(this Link link, Commands command)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
  if (!link.Command(command, result => tcs.TrySetResult(result)))
      tcs.TrySetException(new ConnectionErrorException());
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

With this extension method in place, your calling code is much cleaner:

```
public async Task ExecuteCommand(string userId, string deviceId)
{
  var link = await LinkProviderAsync.GetDeviceLinkAsync(deviceId, userId);
  var commandResponse = await link.CommandAsync(Commands.ConnectToDevice);
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution. And how will this solution perform scalablity wise? I am calling this `ExecuteCommand` in asp.net web api with many concurrent users. Hence my initial attempt to make the process async, as to not hog threads in the thread pool.

Comment: @Zapnologica The above code doesn't block, because await waits asynchronously. So it should be good scalability-wise.

Comment: Just a question, to help me understand the concept better. What sort of frequency will this check the variable at? As you can see in my initall code i was only checking every 200ms as the dll I am calling is a slow action and I can only really expect a response in ~800ms

Comment: @Zapnologica: It doesn't check at any frequency. It uses the callback as a notification.

Comment: Oh, that is totally ideal. So no overhead of checking un-necessarily, and it will return the instant the callback is issued. That is perfect. :)

Comment: @StephenCleary While trying to implement this solution I thought of an issue, which im hoping you are able to help me with.  How do I time-out? in my original code I have a time-out counter which will throw a time-out exception after 15 seconds. Is there a way to add a time-out to the `TaskCompletionSource`

Comment: @Zapnologica: It's best to use `CancellationTokenSource` for timeout support (where "timeout" is just one kind of cancellation). The `*Async` methods take a `CancellationToken` which will trigger when the timeout expires.

Comment: and is a CancellationTokenSource going to behave the same way as the TaskCompletionSource you showed me?

Comment: No. You can find a good overview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with combining `async` and `ref` is that code inside an `async` function can run even after the method returns. So, if you did something like:

```
async Task BlockForResponseAsync(ref bool localFlag)
{
    while (!localFlag)
    {
        ...
    }
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    bool flag = false;
    BlockForResponseAsync(ref flag); // note: no await here
}
```

Then the local variable `flag` would stop existing after `SomeMethod()` returned, but `BlockForResponseAsync()`, which has a reference to that variable, could still be executing. This is why the above code won't compile.

Basically, what you need is a *closure*, and in C#, `ref` doesn't create closures, but lambdas do. This means you can write your method like this:

```
async Task BlockForResponseAsync(Func<bool> localFlagFunc)
{
    while (!localFlagFunc())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
bool flag = false;
var task = BlockForResponseAsync(() => flag);

// other code here

flag = true;
await task; // to make sure BlockForResponseAsync() completed successfully
```

This way also indicates your intention better. `ref` usually means something like: "give me a variable with some value, and I will change that value", which is not what you want here. On the other hand `Func<T>` means "give me something that I can use retrieve some value, potentially multiple times".

Comment: hmm, very interesting approach, I must admit I didn't know that such things existed. I will certainly have a look into this.